# How large could an aerogel planet get?

Tags: science-based, planets, materials

Most of the world's lightest known materials are aerogels. In recent years, their mechanical strength has greatly improved, due to the creation of composites, crosslinked forms, and especially graphene aerogels.

The mechanical properties of [commercially available](http://www.buyaerogel.com/product/airloy-x103/) aerogels seem pretty impressive given their low bulk densities; I presume even more impressive figures are being produced by researchers.

Very well, what's the point of a material if you can't imagine a planet made out of it? (That's a rhetorical question, let's not VTC!)

My question: How big could an aerogel planet get?

I assume it's limited by either gravity near the core causing the material to pancake, or by temperature,or a combination of the two, but unlike aerogel, I'm dense; I have no idea how to calculate it.

Any class of aerogel, or other light material with a contiguous or mostly contiguous solid phase, with the solid and other phases distributed on a sub millimetre scale,  with less than 0.6 g/cm3 is fair game. Composites are OK.

It should currently exist and have had its bulk mechanical properties measured, not inferred from theory or microanalysis only. The planet must be able to exist for at least 10000 years.

Obviously, it's extremely improbable that it will form naturally. We need not justify its formation.

Disclaimer: I am in no way linked to or benefit from the linked aerogel website.

Comment: Technically you can consider gas giants aerogel planets, they are full of air without any need for it to be contained in a gel. You probably need to provide constraints on when a planet made of aerogel would stop being one.

Comment: Aerogel has to have a solid matrix by definition; a gas is not an aerogel. But I take your point. I've added a requirement that there has to be a contiguous solid phase.

Comment: I wonder if any currently existing aerogel is actually stable for 10k years in itself, in ideal conditions (say in argon atmosphere and shielded from radiation). If not, then the answer is there's no aerogel that can last this long.

Comment: @Vesper Agreed.

Comment: It seems to me cold lava, or lava rock fits the description of an aerogel.

Comment: Yes, in some sense, it is, it's a solid-air colloid. But its density excludes it here. Maybe the lightest of pumices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- https://cseligman.com/text/planets/internalpressure.htm

Pressure for a planet at r distance from its center

P = g2 (3 / (8 π G)) (1 - (r/R)2)

The thing holds until pressure is less than 0.6MPa for L gel (there is compressible properties at play as well, but eh, for your own excercise), so the r we are interested in equals 0

P = 3 g^2 / (8 π G)

g is gravity at surface g(R) = G M / R^2

So then:

P = 3 G M^2 / R^4 / (8 π)

ro = 3 M / (4 π R^3)  (average density in L case it is 20 kg / m3)

M = ro 4 π R^3 / 3

P = (ro 4 π R^3 / 3)^2 3 G / (R^4 8 π) = ro^2 2/3 π R^2 G

R = sqrt( 3 P /(2 π ro^2 G))

So, we have for L gel

P = 0.6 MPa
ro = 20 kg / m3
G = 6.6743 × 10^-11 m3 / kg s2

Sooo, if I'm not mistaken, **which I easily may in the case**, very much may may, we have

R = ( 3 * 600'000 / (2 3.14 400 6.7 10^-11)^0.5 ~ 3'200'000 m or 3200km

So, if mistakes didn't ruined it then surprisingly not a big number of radius to be 3200 km or diameter 6400 km. (Or in contrary - surprisingly a big number)

For a gas bubble the number would  be more impressive due density decreasing closer to "surface", which may improve situation here as well, as on surface the gel does not need to be that strong.

As for it holding for a 1000 year, you would need decrease radius and make sure the material itself wont degrade that much undercosmic rays(which probably not an issue here, as it decent amount of mass to shield most strained part of the thing its core) and stuff.

Considering gravity of the thing will be minuscule, on its surface, so yeah people probably can be on that fluffy planet, and do not break it with all the typical infrastructure.

Surface gravity will be about 0.018 m/s2

But it also need to consider that the thing is on the brink of collapse, so any disturbance and it may start to self implode(use XXL one at the core area), and will it stop when it starts or not - to answer that it needs a further investigation, leave that "trivial" stuff for homework - *muhaha muhaha*

As for natural occurrence of such things, it may, if there is enough of natural occurrence of building blocks for it, that gel stuf, considering that we may say that it typical for asteroids to be a lose agglomeration of gravel sruff, those recent asteroid missions, but yes it probably not likely situation, it just that it can exist, may be.

### PS

- *From your final equation, the ratio P / ro is all important, which makes sense; those gels all have a ratio of around 20. If these gels can reach r = 3200 km, then some of the new graphene ones will probably be able to form entire planets!* – @Sean OConnor

It is size of a planet, if the calculus are not wrong, it is the size of mars already.

And what is somewhat interesting is that a shell of 100m thickness of gel is equivalent for one meter of ground soil, so reduce the planet by 1km radius and place 10m of soil on top of it and viola it looks like your typical planet.

Density is more valuable reduction than strength of material, 2 times less dense 2 times bigger radius, and 4 times stronger 2 times the radius increase. And making it less dense is easy(as first order of estimation) just cut holes in material and lay it in the way for it to have holes(idk how to describe it, but like your typical pyramide or buildings or cheese have voids/rooms) it does not require change in material technologies, and upper layers has less demands for strength than the core area. So this way if you like to have it the size of this planet, like earth, then few tricks here and there and you may have it.

And 100m your typical regolith mater displaces 10-20km of that gel shell, which compared to the whole radius is subtle change of things, but which creates a peal of soil for any goal and purpose.

That reduction of density for most of the structure, to increase size, can be done by actually create some useful voids in there from typical materials(that sure more artificial creation of the thing direction)

If we take O'Neill cylinder sizes as model to the voids(not for the living, but maybe for some technological purposes), which is 8km diameter x 32 km length, and its 8t per square meter of surface which brings us to average density of 4kg per cubic meter, which is 5 times better than airogels in considerations, it easily can replace half of the volume without compromising average sterngth, and probbaly be even stronger the stuff it replaces. Considering the aspect we can inflate such voids to a pressure it requires at its location, like 6 bar at the core and less and less pressure outwards.

- inflating is not required, but just in case if strength of that cylinder is not good enough, for some reason, there is a way to bring it up to required spec
- inflating also adds mass 6 bar of air is 9kg/m3, but still it better than gel density
- voids in pure airogel also can be inflated, but gass will permiate the thing, and it hard to tell the whole dynamics, but km's of airogel will have gas barrier properties, which also may have interesting effects like gas mixture separation, like refining columns. Despite it appearant permiability it will take quite a time for highpressure pockets to dissolve and average the whole planet thing, as it takes km's 10's km to do so, go trough a membrane of a sort.

So that initial size is very rudementary consideration of such a structure and plenty of thing still can be done to inflate the size by designing it in a better way, if we play with density by design how and in which way we place the matter, which other structures we can combine it with etc.

It actually quite interesting space structure to think about.

So carving out an asteroid, nah, old day stuff

Airogel asteroids - yez, yez!

Comment: Wow,fab answer,  thank you very much! Ftom your final equation, the ratio P / ro is all important, which makes sense; those gels all have a ratio of around 20. If these gels can reach r = 3200 km, then some of the new graphene ones will probably be able to form entire planets!